# jQuery - How can I find the same href attr on document?

Tags: jquery, find, href, document, attr

edit: delete dev-link!

At the bottom you'll see a sitemap navigation. If I hover a navpoint at bottom, it also should be highlight (addClass) the same Navpoint at my top navigation. You'll see the Links are the same. For exp. there's only six ...

I write the "`href attr.`" on `mouseHover` into my variable "`aHref`":

```
$(".psSitemap a").hover(
    function() {
        var aHref = $( this ).attr('href');
        console.log(aHref);

        // addClass 'active' to the comparable Top Navigation Item href is the same!
    }, function() {
        // removeClass 'active' at Top Navigation
    }
);
```

But how can I also "find" the comparable ahref.attr at my document?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you, and I've just updated my answer for the question (which you posted as answer) if it's possible to simplify the hover function. A little advice regarding Stackoverflow rules - you shouldn't post additional questions as answers, but you can just add this as update/edit to your original question. When posted as answers, additional questions most likely will be flagged as "Not an answer" and deleted. For more information you can check http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `var aHref = $( this ).attr('href');` the matching top navigation link  is

```
$(".full-size a[href='" + aHref +  "']")
```

For the question if it's possible to write the function to change the matching topnav link on hovering sitemap links in an easier way - it can be reduced by using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of adding and removing the class in two separate functions and not declaring any variables (though this can be useful for readability, it's not needed) :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".psSitemap a").hover(
    function () {
        $(".full-size a[href='" + $(this).attr('href') + "']").toggleClass('comparable');
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
a {
  color: #000;
}
.comparable {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="full-size">
  <li><a href="first.html">First</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="second.html">Second</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="third.html">Third</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="psSitemap">
  <li><a href="first.html">First</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="second.html">Second</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="third.html">Third</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {



  $( ".psSitemap a" ).hover(


    function() {

      // add href from hover pos.
      var aHref = $( this ).attr('href');
      // comparable 
      var topNav = $(".full-size a[href='" + aHref +  "']");


      // addClass 'active' to the comparable Top Navigation Item          
      $(topNav).addClass('comparable');



    }, function() {
      var aHref = $( this ).attr('href');
      var topNav = $(".full-size a[href='" + aHref +  "']");

      // removeClass 'active' at Top Navigation
      $(topNav).removeClass('comparable');
    }
  );





});
```

Thanks Matthias for your help. It works, but I think I can write it easier?! What do you think ..?